# Error: [object Object]/XMLHttpRequest cannot load in Angular2 when pulling XML data as JSON

Tags: javascript, json, xml, angular, xmlhttprequest

I am attempting to pull in XML data as JSON. When doing so, I get the following errors:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml. No     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.   Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

Also my alert error code just states [object Object]

http-test.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { Http } from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@Injectable()
export class HttpTestService{
  constructor (private _http: Http){}
  getData(){
    return this._http.get('http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml')
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

http-test.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {HttpTestService} from './http-test.service';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'http-test',
  template:`
    <button (click)="onTestGet()">Test GET Request</button><br>
    <p>Output:</p>
    <textarea id="txtOut" rows="45" cols="100">{{getData}}</textarea>
  `,
  providers: [HttpTestService]
})

export class HttpTestComponent{
  getData: any;
  postData: string;

  constructor (private _httpService: HttpTestService){}

  onTestGet(){
    this._httpService.getTeams()
    .subscribe(
    data => this.getData = JSON.stringify(data),
    error => alert(error),
    () => console.log("Finished")
    );
  }
}
```

This code works when I pull from JSON formatted URLs but not XML. Not sure what is the problem or how I might fix it. Thanks!

Comment: It works if you get JSONP data, or the server uses CORS headers, otherwise it won't work due to the same-origin policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This has nothing to do with your angular App, but the fact that there is no [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) header in your response from the server. To prove this, download [this plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), and your app will automagically work. This of course, is not good for users, but can save you some pain during development. It seems like you are just trying to learn things so this might just be an acceptable use case. You could also try using a different API that respons with CORs.
2. Do not alert with errors. They violate web best practices, most users will just ignore/close them, and as you've noticed they don't show objects or arrays. I would suggest `console.error('Error! ', error)`, and some sort of flash messaging service. But you may also want to check out the network tab in your browser.

[image]

You'll notice that actually the server responds with a 200 OK, but browser still blocks the XHR because of the lack of headers.